# What can I check to fix broken FTP connection?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ftp

I'm trying to setup remote access for my home PC through ssh, FTP & VNC. Ssh is working, it's time for FTP. My "server" runs under Manjaro with vsftpd as FTP-server. First, I'm trying to access it with FileZilla from Win10 machine, here is connection log:

```
Status: Connecting to 192.168.50.10:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/home/***" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,50,10,127,51).
Command:    LIST
Error:  Transfer connection interrupted: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Connection closed by server
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I made a port forwarding for FTP in my router and ran test from https://ftptest.net/, here is log:

```
Warning: Allowing fallback to plaintext FTP is insecure. You should use explicit FTP over TLS.
Status: Resolving address of ***
Status: Connecting to ***
Warning: The entered address does not resolve to an IPv6 address.
Status: Connected, waiting for welcome message...
Reply: 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Command: CLNT https://ftptest.net on behalf of ***
Reply: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
Command: AUTH TLS
Reply: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
Warning: Server refused AUTH TLS, trying deprecated AUTH SSL fallback.
Command: AUTH SSL
Reply: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
Warning: Server refused AUTH SSL, falling back to insecure plaintext FTP.
Command: USER ***
Reply: 331 Please specify the password.
Command: PASS ******
Reply: 230 Login successful.
Command: SYST
Reply: 215 UNIX Type: L8
Command: FEAT
Reply: 211-Features:
Reply: EPRT
Reply: EPSV
Reply: MDTM
Reply: PASV
Reply: REST STREAM
Reply: SIZE
Reply: TVFS
Reply: UTF8
Reply: 211 End
Warning: The server does not indicate MLSD support. MLSD uses a well-specified listing format. Without MLSD, directory listings have to be obtained using LIST which uses an unspecified output format.
Command: PWD
Reply: 257 "/home/***" is the current directory
Status: Current path is /home/***
Command: TYPE I
Reply: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command: PASV
Reply: 227 Entering Passive Mode (*,*,*,*,43,142).
Command: LIST
Status: Data connection established.
Error: Could not read from socket: Connection reset by peer
```

ftptest.net says that this error is due

> - A common cause for this problem are broken routers and/or firewalls that interrupt the connection.
> - Some broken or badly configured servers can also interrupt the connection prematurely.

I disabled win10 firewall, router firewall, what can I check further?

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying to login as my Manjaro's user, so I think this user has all permissions to it's home dir. Anyway, I tried to set permissions 777 to home dir - it didn't help. Also I added my user to `vsftpd.userlists` and added this file to `vsftpd.config` - still no luck.

I noted in `sudo systemctl status vsftpd` that

> vsftpd[14483]: pam_listfile(vsftpd:auth): Couldn't open /etc/ftpusers

so I created it, and added my user here. Now FileZilla says:

> Response: 530 Login incorrect.

, but I'm sure my user and it's password are correct, so I deleted my user from `/etc/ftpusers` and now I have the same errors as before except missing `/etc/ftpusers`.

I'm complete newbie in net technologies, so I'm just tried to establish sftp session in Mobaxterm, unsuccessfully:

> Connection error: unable to connect to server

**UPDATE 2:**

I'am still unable to setup FTP, but SFTP works well, so I've accepted the answer.

Comment: I'd check your FTP server config, and make sure the user in question has access to the directory in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can run `ssh` then `sftp` is available. It's just like FTP but with ssh's inbuilt security. The interface looks just the same.